# How to retrieve the page title in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to retrieve the title of a remote webpage. I found this js on the internet but
someone can tell me what does "$.request("fetch_title", { url: c })" do in this function: ?

```
function fetch_title() {
var a = $("#url-field"),
    b = a.find(".NO_URL"),
    a = a.find(".title-status"),
    c = $("#url").val();
  if (c) {
    if (!$('form#newlink textarea[name="title"]').val() || confirm("This will replace your existing title, proceed?")) 
        a.show().text(reddit.status_msg.loading), 
        b.hide(), 
        $.request("fetch_title", { url: c })
  } else a.hide(), b.show().text("a url is required")
}
```

Comment: This is out of context.  Can you supply the name of the library you are using that $ belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `jQuery.request()` function in core jQuery, so it's likely implemented by a plug-in. The closest I've found on Google is [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/), which is described as a "component library for jQuery". However, there's no indication from the documentation that using `$` in place of `amplify` would work.

Taken from the page linked above:

> amplify.request is an abstraction layer that can be used for any kind of request for data. amplify.request sets out to separate the data retrieval and caching mechanisms from data requestors.

It seems to be a request for the title of a page based on the specified URL from user input, but the exact specifics of the request would be elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the title of a page, simply use jquery.get and search for the title in the response like so:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    var matches = data.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
    var title = matches[1];
});
```

The title will no be in the title variable.